# If $A \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is not closed, show that there is a continuous function $f: A \to \mathbb{R}$ which is unbounded.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity

If $A \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is not closed, show that there is a continuous function $f: A \to \mathbb{R}$ which is unbounded. *Hint:* If $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \backslash A$, but $x \notin int(\mathbb{R}^{n} \backslash A)$, let $f(y) = \frac{1}{|y - x|}$.

I'm having trouble coming up with a function. The only thing that comes to my mind is that the hint they gave could be a function used to show the claimed result, but that would mean at least in my thought process that $y$ is approaching some value of $x$ but never arrives at it and as such the function will blow up. If this is the idea that should be conveyed then I'm struggling to convey it more formally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is precisely the one given by the hint.

Suppose $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is not closed. Therefore, there are limit points of $A$ which are not elements of $A$. Let $x$ be one such point, and define $f : A \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(y) = \|x-y\|^{-1}$. Since $x \notin A$, this function is well-defined on $A$. Moreover, since $y \mapsto \|y\|$ is a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}^n$, $f$ is also a continuous function.

To see that $f$ is unbounded on $A$, fix a sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} \subset A$ such that $x_n \to x$. Then for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\|x-x_n\| < \varepsilon$ for each $n \geq N$. Let $M > 0$ be arbitrary. Then there is an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\|x-x_n\|< M^{-1}$ for each $n \geq N$. That is, $f(x_n) > M$ for each $n \geq N$. Since $M$ was arbitrary, we conclude that $f$ is unbounded on $A$.

---

To address the question in the comments, suppose that

1. A set $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is defined to be *open* if for each $x \in U$ there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $y \in U$ for each $y$ satisfying $\|x-y\| < \varepsilon$.
2. A set $F$ is defined to be *closed* if $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus F$ is open.
3. The point $x$ is a *limit point* of the set $A$ if there exists a sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} \subseteq A$ with $x_n \ne x$ for each $n$ such that $x_n \to x$.

How do we know that a closed set contains its limit points?

Suppose $F$ is closed, and suppose $x$ is a limit point of $F$. Fix a sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} \subseteq A$ with $x_n \ne x$ for each $n$ such that $x_n \to x$. Then for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\|x-x_n\| < \varepsilon$ for each $n \geq N$.

Is $x \notin F$? For the sake of contradiction, assume so. Since $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus F$ is open, we can fix $\overline{\varepsilon} > 0$ such that for any $y$ satisfying $\|x - y\| < \overline{\varepsilon}$, we have $y \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus F$. On the other hand, we can fix $\overline{N} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\|x - x_n\| < \overline{\varepsilon}$ for each $n \geq \overline{N}$. But each of these $x_n$ is an element of $F$. This is a contradiction.

Comment: I have a question with regards to your solution. I've taken an analysis course before and in that course I learned to show this result using the sequential definition just as you have. But in this current course the only way we have defined a set being closed is by the idea of it being the complement of an open set. How could I express this idea in that form?

Comment: @dc3rd How has your course defined an open set?

Comment: The usual $\epsilon$ neigbourhood definition. That is, a set is open if for every element in the set there exists an open neighbourhood around each element such that the neigbourhood is fully contained in the open set.

Comment: @dc3rd See my amendment to the original answer.

Comment: Above and beyond what I expected. Thank you for your help. Out of curiosity, how were you able to think out the solution so quickly. I get the aspect of experience, but you seemingly were ablt to put all of the pieces of the argument together very quickly.

Comment: You're welcome. To your other question, it really is just experience. After a while problems like these all "smell" the same. But that comes from continuously pushing at the frontier of problems you find very difficult and accumulating ideas and tricks from them.